# specify name and id to Drop down razor technique asp dot net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-select

I have asp web form and i'm using razor technique to post that form,
problem is that, i want to know that how to specify ID and NAME attribute to razor dropdown list because, in next step, i'm getting the form value by using the ID and NAME attribute..

VIEW code is :

```
@Html.DropDownList("ID", (SelectList) ViewBag.list, " -- Select Business Type -- ")
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult coverage()
{
    var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<businessDropDownModel>("businesDropDownSP");
    ViewBag.list = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "BusinessTypeName", "----select----");

    return View();
}
```

MODEL:

```
public class businessDropDownModel
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string BusinessTypeName { set; get; } 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument in `@Html.DropDownList("MyIdAndName", (SelectList) ViewBag.list, " -- Select Business Type -- ")` is both the id and the name of the `select` tag.

So,

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyIdAndName", (SelectList) ViewBag.list, " -- Select Business Type -- ")
```

would render

```
<select id="MyIdAndName" name="MyIdAndName">...</select>
```

Comment: how do you call that dropdown id in the controller?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to set the name and id or other attributes you can use the html attributes option.

NOTE: the method has a quirk: you can use the attributes dictionary to override the "id", but **not** the "name".

example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Selected", Model.SelectList, "First Option", new { name = "Name", id = "id"})
```

will render:

```
<select id="id" name="Selected">...</select>
```

So the upshot is: if you want name and id to be different, set the name *parameter* to what you want the name to be, and use the dictionary to override the id.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to set the Id to something different than the Name, you can use the htmlAttributes parameter to set the Id of the control. You still use the first parameter in the DropDownList helper to set the Name of the control.

```
@Html.DropDownList( "Job.DefaultProfitCenter", (SelectList)ViewBag.DefaultProfitCenter, " -- Select -- ", new { id = "Job_DefaultProfitCenter" } )
```

This will generate the following html for the drop down list:

```
<select id="Job_DefaultProfitCenter" name="Job.DefaultProfitCenter">
    <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
    <option value="0">Option 1</option>
</select>
```