# "Cannot convert type 'ViewModels.DropDownVM' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'" when Populating DropDown with MySQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have loosely followed: [specify name and id to Drop down razor technique asp dot net mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332527/specify-name-and-id-to-drop-down-razor-technique-asp-dot-net-mvc4)

What my desired end result is is that I have a view which has two dropdowns which are populated with values from the 'ww' column in a DB. Once a user selects a start and end and clicks a submit button, it would then pass the selected values to another `ActionMethod` that then takes those values and performs a similar query and directs to a different view with a different set of controls.

However, I'm getting a

> "Cannot convert type 'ViewModels.DropDownVM' to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'"

error at the following line in my code and haven't been able to figure out how to fix the issue so that everything runs smoothly.

```
@Html.DropDownList("WWStart", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLWWStart, " -- Select Starting Work Week -- ")
```

I have the following:

ViewModels/DropDownVM.cs snippet:

```
public class DropDownVM
{
    public int SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    //public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
}
```

IndicatorController Index():

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var context = new taskDBContext())
        {
            var DDLWWQuery = (from wq in context.taskSet
                              select new
                              {
                                  wq.ww
                              }).Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.ww);
            // The controls have a Work Week Range so we need both a start and end control
            var DDLWWStartVM = new DropDownVM();
            DDLWWStartVM.Categories = new SelectList(DDLWWQuery, "ww", "ww");
            ViewBag.DDLWWStart = DDLWWStartVM;
            //ViewBag.DDLWWStart = new SelectList(DDLWWQuery.AsEnumerable(), "ww", "ww", "-- Select Starting WW --");

            //ViewBag.DDLWWEnd = new SelectList(DDLWWQuery.AsEnumerable(), "ww", "ww", "-- Select Ending WW --");

            var DDLWWEndVM = new DropDownVM();
            DDLWWEndVM.Categories = new SelectList(DDLWWQuery, "ww", "ww");
            ViewBag.DDLWWEnd = DDLWWEndVM;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Index View Snippet:

```
@model IEnumerable<TaskTracker.ViewModels.DropDownVM>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Indicator: Step One of Two";
}

<h2>Indicators</h2>

<p>This is currently being refined.</p>


<div>Create Indicator: Step One of Two - Select Work Week Range</div>

using (Html.BeginForm("StepTwo", "Indicator", new { wwStartSelect = WWStart.Categories.Text, wwEndSelect = WWEnd.Categories.Text }))
{
<div>Select Starting Work Week</div>

@Html.DropDownList("WWStart", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLWWStart, " -- Select Starting Work Week -- ")

<div>Select Ending Work Week</div>

@Html.DropDownList("WWEnd", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLWWEnd, " -- Select Ending Work Week -- ")

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input type="submit" title="Next Step" value="Next Step" />
}
```

How can I resolve this error by fixing my code to get the desired result?

Comment: don't you need to put `.Categories`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not casting the right object. You should cast it to the Categories Property ... see below

```
@Html.DropDownList("WWStart", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLWWStart.Categories, " -- Select Starting Work Week -- ")
@Html.DropDownList("WWEnd", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLWWEnd.Categories, " -- Select Ending Work Week -- ")
```